# Parsing model partial DisplayName to view model template

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

If I have a Model with a partial file

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ClassAMetadata))]
public partial class ClassA: IStructualObject
{
}

public class ClassAMetadata
{
    [DisplayName("Var B:")]
    public object VarB { get; set; }
}
```

And Var B is a DateTime!

Then I have a ViewModel (ClassAViewwModel) for the controller using ClassA, in this ViewModel I ClassA and it also have a DateTimeViewModel of VarB, the reason for this is that in my application DateTime is shown as 3 fields Date, Hour and Minute.

I then created a Template for my DateTimeViewModel. See the code:

```
    @model ViewModels.DateTimeViewModel
<div >
    <span class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m)
    </span>
    <span class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { id = "participating_airborne_@ViewData_" + ViewData["cssname"] + "_resource_date", @class="datepicker dato", maxlength="10"})
    </span>
    <span class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Hour, new { id = "participating_airborne_" + ViewData["cssname"] + "_resource_hours", @class = "time", maxlength = "2" })
    </span>:<span class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Minute, new { id = "participating_airborne_" + ViewData["cssname"] + "_resource_minutes", @class = "time", maxlength = "2" })
    </span>
    <span>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Hour)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Minute)
    </span>
</div>
```

What I then want is to somehow get the DisplayName from my VarB to be shown when I do @Html.LabelFor(m => m) on my DateTimeViewModel (Or something similar) so I need a way to read that Partial information, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get display name for current model from model metadata, like this:

```
ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName()
```

**EDIT:**

If you have view model:

```
public class ClassA
{
    [DisplayName("Var B:")]
    public DateTimeViewModel VarB { get; set; }
}
```

And then in ClassA view you render that property like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.VarB)
```

Then it should use your DateTimeViewModel template and be able to extract the display name from model metadata.

Comment: If I am in my View with the ClassAViewModel then if I do what you write I will get the displayname for ClassA, I cant seem to make it give me the Display for the properties in ClassAViewModel